Trace and Norm of an element $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ is equal to Trace and Determinant of Linear Transform $ T(\beta) = \alpha \beta$
I'm trying to solve the following exercise :
Exercise: Let $\mathbb{{F}_{q^{n}}}$ a extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{{F}_{q^{n}}}$. Define the $\mathbb{F}_q$ - linear map: $T : \mathbb{{F}_{q^{n}}} \rightarrow \mathbb{{F}_{q^{n}}}$ by $T(\beta)  = \alpha \beta$. Show that:
a) $\alpha$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $T$.
b) Let ${\alpha , \alpha^{q}, ... , \alpha^{{q}^{n-1}}}$ the conjugates of $\alpha$, if $Tr(\alpha)$ is equal to sum of conjugates of $\alpha$ and $N(\alpha)$ is equal to product of conjugates then:  $Tr(\alpha)$ is equal to Trace of T and $N(\alpha)$ is equal to determinant of $T$.
I was thinking about showing that the characteristic polynomial of T is equal to $(x- \alpha)(x- \alpha^{q})...(x-\alpha^{{q}^{n-1}})$, is that correct?
But I wasn't successful in showing this, could anyone help me by giving me some not very advanced tips?

Is this a duplicate of this older question? Or of  this?

See also this for the trace.

Yes, you indeed need to show that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is equal $(x - \alpha)(x - \alpha^q)\cdots (x - \alpha^{q^{n-1}})$.
For the basic case where $\Bbb F_{q^n} = \Bbb F_q(\alpha)$, it suffices to note that

The characteristic polynomial of $T$ has coefficients in $\Bbb F_q$
Because $\alpha$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, each conjugate of $\alpha$ is also a root of the characteristic polynomial
The degree of the characteristic polynomial is $n$

Once you have the formula for the characteristic polynomial, it suffices to note that within that polynomial, the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is equal to $-\text{tr}(T)$ and the constant term is equal to $\det(T)$.
For the general case, suppose that $\Bbb F_{q^n}$ is presented as $\Bbb F_q[t]/p(t)$, and that $\alpha \in \Bbb F_{q^n}$ has minimal polynomial $m$ over $\Bbb F_q[t]$, note that we must have $m \mid n$. We find that the subspaces
$$
\Bbb F_q[\alpha], \quad t\,\Bbb F_q[\alpha], \dots,\quad  t^{n/m}\Bbb F_q[\alpha]
$$
are complementary $T$-invariant subspaces, where the action of $T$ over the subspace is equivalent to that of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb F_q[\alpha]$. By the basic case, we can conclude that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ over each of these subspaces is $\prod_{k=1}^{m}(x - \alpha^{q^k})$. The desired conclusion follows.

An example with non-distinct conjugates:
Take $q = 3, n = 4$. I will stick to the presentation
$$
\Bbb F_{3^4} = \Bbb F_3[t]/\langle t^4 + 2t^3 + 2 \rangle
$$
Take $\alpha = t^3 + t^2 + 1$. Note that $\alpha^2 = -1$. Its only conjugate is $-\alpha$.
Note that $T$ has two invariant subspaces: the elements of the form $(c_0 + c_1 \alpha)$, and the elements of the form $(c_0 + c_1\alpha)t$. Relative to the basis $\{1,\alpha, t, t\alpha\}$, we find that $T$ has the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0},
$$
and all claims of the exercise hold true.

This is the basic case, but in general it is possible that there are repetitions among the conjugates. It works exactly like this when $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}=\Bbb{F}_q(\alpha)$. The wording on the OP was not crystal clear, whether that is the case. Probably it was intended to be read that way?

@JyrkiLahtonen I should have thought about it a bit more carefully but I read "Let ${\alpha , \alpha^{q}, ... , \alpha^{{q}^{n-1}}}$ the conjugates of $\alpha$" as implying that the list consists of distinct conjugates. Also, I'm pretty sure that the statement fails to be true if $\Bbb F_q(\alpha) \subsetneq \Bbb F_q^n$

@JyrkiLahtonen, So are you saying that the statement fails if the conjugates are repeated or the statement is correct even in this case but it is the argument that fails? Sorry, I didn't understand correctly. From what I understand in the original exercise statement, it is not required that the conjugates be distinct.

@BenGrossmann, Thanks for the feedback, you said the assertion fails in this case, would you have an example?

@Monteiro_C I just went through an example and it seems that I was wrong. It seems this is indeed correct for the case of repeating conjugates, and that the repeated roots of the characteristic polynomial correspond to $T$ acting the same way over several invariant subspaces.

No. The statement is still ok. Each conjugate is repeated exactly $m=[\Bbb{F}_{q^n}:\Bbb{F}_q(\alpha)]$ times. So the trace of $\alpha$ is multiplied by $m$ to get the trace of the linear transformation, and the norm raised to power $m$ to get the determinant. See for example the answer by Rene Schipperus.

@JyrkiLahtonen I think we actually agree but you might have misinterpreted my comment. I had previously stated that the statement was not ok, but I have since concluded that the statement is ok

Yes, @BenGrossmann. Earlier today the time I spent on this thread was dedicated to searching for a duplicate, so I missed your comment. Sorry about that.

This may be a cleaner description of what happens when $\alpha$ does not generate the full field extension.

@JyrkiLahtonen It seems I have too little patience in looking for duplicates before answering. Do you think I should delete this answer?

That happens to us all. I am not happy with any of the duplicate candidates, so I don't see a need for deletion. Can't blame you, really. Happens to me often enough that I later get second thoughts about my answers.

@JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for the clarification and for the other questions you attached, they were very enlightening ;)

@JyrkiLahtonen I appreciate that perspective, thanks

@BenGrossmann Thank you very much for the answer and for the example, if possible I would like to ask you not to delete it ;)

Note: I still have difficulty finding questions similar to mine here, can anyone give me any tips?

@Monteiro_C You can use google to search within the site, approach0 can be helpful, and the in-site search function lets you restrict to certain tags. In the end of the day, it is difficult to find certain answers here, even with all that

I appreciate you considering the matter.
